# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "name"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

when i want to display the list in my jsp page.i'm getting this error

my foreach loop to display the list:

```
<c:forEach  var="list" items="${consultantsList}" varStatus="iter">
<c:out value="${list.name}"></c:out>
 </c:forEach>
```

my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/patient")
public class PatientController {

@Autowired
private PatientService patientService;

@RequestMapping(value="/registerPatient.htm")
public ModelAndView getRegisterPage()
{
    ModelAndView modelAndView=new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("register");
    List<Consultant> list=patientService.getAllConsultant();
    modelAndView.addObject("consultantsList",list);
    modelAndView.addObject("patient", new Patient());

    return modelAndView;
}
```

when i completely remove the foreach loop the jsp will display without any exception.

Exception:
`org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested        exception is org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path        '/WEB-INF/jsp/i1-smhBaseLayout.jsp'.
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.ja        va:656)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)`
root cause:

```
org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/jsp/i1-smhBaseLayout.jsp'.
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:692)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
```

Comment: Are you sure patientService.getAllConsultant() is not null? If null return new ArrayList<>(0) in patientService.getAllConsultant(). Or better an immmutable List.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ${consultantsList} here is

> ${consultantsList.name}

is a List, however i am attempting to access it as if it is a single User. This is not valid. In EL, a List can only be accessed with an integer index, indicating the position of the list item you'd like to access, like so the below statement gives me the names

> ${consultant[1]}

Answer (score 0):

Your `<c:out>` tag isn't written properly, and as a result isn't being closed. You have this:

```
<c:out value="${list.name}"</c:out>
```

It should look like this:

```
<c:out value="${list.name}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap the for each with an if condition checking the size and null check for the consultantsList object. Please paste the exception coming.

Comment: a bit more stack trace after this line
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803) root cause

Comment: i may be going out of the way but can you check the version of JSP tag library and update it with the latest version..just try

Comment: thanx for you time..i got the answer The `${consultantsList}` here is
   `${consultantsList.name}`
   
is a List<Consultant>, however i am attempting to access it as if it is a single User. This is not valid. In EL, a List can only be accessed with an integer index, indicating the position of the list item you'd like to access, like so the below statement gives me the names 
  `${consultant[1]}`